# how to create a logic to count the number of the same IP address in an hour with Kusto Query Language

Tags: azure, kql, azure-application-gateway

I understand that Application Gateway can collect client IP address in access logs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/ag/web-application-firewall-logs#access-log

I would like to create a logic to count the number of the request in the same IP in an hour and send alert if it is more than 100 (maybe I will use Azure Functions to run this code every hour).

Can anyone share a sample code to achieve the goal? I believe I need to use KQL, but I am not familiar with it.

Comment: you can make use of [distinct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/distinctoperator) and [count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/countoperator) functions in your kql query. Distinct is to identify the different ip in an hour and by using count you can get its count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an answer from our comment discussion.

You can use the below sample KQL query to pull the list of distinct `Client_IP` with respective count within a specific hour.

```
  AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceType == "APPLICATIONGATEWAYS" and OperationName == "ApplicationGatewayAccess"
|summarize count() by clientIP_s
```